# Implementing delegate methods, but still getting a warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm getting a peculiar warning, specifically this one:

```
warning: class does not implement the 'UIWebViewDelegate' protocol
```

... when I have these methods in my application:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad {
    ...
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad {
    ...
}
```

... and even after setting the UIWebView's delegate to `self`, I still get this warning, and the methods are never called (`NSLog` provides no results.)

Can anyone pinpoint what is happening here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As '@No on in particular' says, your methods aren't declared correctly. That is why the methods aren't called at all.

The warning has a different reason. It is because your interface definition doesn't declare that it implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
...
}
...
@end
```

Whether or not the interface declares the protocol or not is actually of no consequence at runtime, it is just a hint to the compiler that allows it to issue warnings like the one you are seeing, or warnings if you don't implement the methods.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your delegate methods are correct. Shouldn't they be:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry, big typo when transferring to SO... I have these in my source code.